# Get difference number of two dates and subtract it from table laravel HR

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I'm trying to figure out how to make this work I have a Leave Application(which is currently just a form that stores the data) which is supposed to remove the "Days Granted" like Annual Leaves or Sick Leaves based on the dates from them for example "from 27/08/2020" and "to 30/08/2020" which is 3 days I want to get those numbers from between the dates and in the user table on the leave_days_granted field(which always has default value 20) to remove it from there so leave_days_granted - 3 = 17 something like this so I can display it on the view how many that user has left

I have added this in the user model

```
class User
{
    public function leaveBalance()
    {
        $daysUsed = $this->leaves->map->numberOfDays()->sum();
        return $this->leave_days_granted - $daysUsed;
    }

    // You can also add a helper to make your controller more readable.
    public function hasAvailableLeave()
    {
        return $this->leaveBalance() > 0;
    }

    public function leaves()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Leave::class);
    }

}
```

And this is added in the Leave Model

```
class Leave
{
    protected $dates = ['from', 'to'];

    public function numberOfDays()
    {
        return $this->from->diffInDays($to);
    }
}
```

So here I don't get why this isn't working it's not changing anything in the database when I request a leave and I'm not sure now if I'm supposed to add something more on the Leave controller to call this or the View of the Leave

This is how I get the dates on the view

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('leaves.store')}}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>From Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control @error('from') is-invalid @enderror" name="from" required="">

                                @error('from')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker1" type="text" class="form-control @error('to') is-invalid @enderror" name="to" required="">
```

This is the form [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K11Bq.jpg) This is the users table [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka4Cm.jpg) This is the leaves table [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kQsy.jpg)

This is the LeaveController

```
 public function index()
    {

        if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
        {
            $users = User::all();
            $leaves = Leave::latest()->paginate(5);
            return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves'),compact('users'));
        }

        $role = Auth::guard('web')->user()->role_id;
        if($role == 1)
        {
            return view('unauthorized');
        }
        else
        {
            $leaves = Leave::latest()->paginate(5);
            return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves'));
        }
    
        
    }
    public function create()
     {
        $leaves = Leave::latest()->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5);
        return view('leave.create',compact('leaves'));
    }
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'from'=>'required',
            'to'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required', 
            'type'=>'required'
            ]);
            $data=$request->all();
            $data['user_id']=auth()->user()->id;
            $data['message']='';
            $data['status']=0;
            $leave =Leave::create($data);
            
            $admins = Admin::all();
            $users = User::where('role_id', 2)->get();

            foreach ($admins as $admins) {
                foreach($users as $users){
                $admins->notify(new LeaveSent($leave));
                $users->notify((new LeaveSent($leave)));
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Leave Created');

    }
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: You mean to post the sql here?

Comment: Yep. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I added the Leave Controller I believe that has the SQL that can help, I hope its the right one(I'm very new to this so sorry for inconveniences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have one user with 20 days availables for vacations or permissions.

You need that for each  leave request, this count days of leave,  and  deduct of days availables for each user

I make this:

1. transform dates in object Carbon
2. get diff days
3. update days availables for user
4. In your controller

   ```
    //transform dates in object Carbon
    $from = Carbon::parse($request->from);
    $to = Carbon::parse($request->to);
    //get diff days
    $diff = $from->diffInDays($to)
    //find user and deduct days
    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->days_availables = $user->days_availables - $diff
    $user->update();
   ```

you learn more use Carbon library in: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Thank you I configured some stuff that works for me more but yeah the overall code is this and it works well